# Modernizr / Yepnope returns "n is undefined" error when used in GreaseMonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, modernizr, userscripts, yepnope

When yepnope (which comes by default bundled in Modernizr) is used on a GreaseMonkey userscript that **[@runs-at document-start](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at)**, the whole userscript fails with the error "n is undefined", which means maxified that "firstScript is undefined".

Indeed it refers to the line:
`insBeforeObj          = isGeckoLTE18 ? docElement : firstScript.parentNode,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the DOM is not yet loaded at GreaseMonkey document-start, this fails.

Workaround 1: Don't use yepnope with Modernizr, this isn't mandatory.

Workaround 2: Run Modernizr/yepnope at document-end. That's probably where you're starting to manipulate the DOM, aren't you?

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', _runAtDocumentEnd, false);

function _runAtDocumentEnd() {

/* insert Modernizr/Yepnope library here */

}
```

Workaround 3: Run at document-end. But since you've explicitely wanted to run it at document-start, this is probably not an acceptable workaround.